# Explain the anomaly in Bemidbar 2:20

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, bamidbar-parsha

In viewing the 4 groups of 3 encampments mentioned at the beginning of sidra Bemidbar, I noticed that regarding the 2nd tribe in each group, the Torah uses the phrase והחונים עליו ("The ones camping next to him"). See Bemidbar 2:5, 2:12 and 2:27.

For some reason, 2:20 regarding the tribe of Ephraim, the word והחונים is missing. Why?

**Conjecture:** The group "leader" in the 3rd group is Menashe, Ephraim's brother. Perhaps, that fact gives Ephraim a "special status"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Netziv in Ha'amek Davar addresses this issue:

> ועליו מטה מנשה – משונה הלשון כאן. ויש נפקא מינה במשמעות, ד״החונים
>   עליו״ משמע כקטן הנסמך על הגדול, וחנייתו ומילוי צרכיו תלויים בדעת מי
>   שגדול ממנו. משא״כ משמעות ״ועליו״ להיפך, דעת הגדול על הקטן והוא מנהיגו.
>   והיינו, דאע״ג דאפרים היה ראש הדגל, היינו משום שהנהגת המדבר היתה נסיית
>   ובזה גדול כח אפרים, אבל מ״מ מה שנדרשו להליכות העולם היה מנשה גדול
>   מאפרים. ומזה הטעם במנין דפרשת פינחס היה מנשה קודם לאפרים (להלן כו,כט),
>   משום דכניסתם לארץ היתה יותר נוטה להליכות הטבע, ובזה מנשה קודם, כמו
>   שכתבתי בספר בראשית (מח,יד). משום הכי כתיב כאן ״ועליו״, דמנשה הנהיגו
>   לאפרים בהליכות העולם.

According to the Netziv, the implication of והחונים עליו is that this tribe is dependent on the earlier mentioned tribe, whereas עליו without החונים means that the second tribe sustains the first one. In the desert, Ephraim was the leader but only because they were sustained through miracles. In fact, however, the tribe of Menashe has precedence in terms of earthly sustenance; this is why in the enumeration prior to the entry into the land, which would require the ability  to sustain themselves through natural means, Menashe is listed first.

Comment: You can link to the Netziv at http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bemidbar/2.20#e0n6 and also consider that Menashe was the older brother even though Ephraim was first in the bracha of Yaakov. Thus, I would read the Netzive as pointing this out as ד״החונים עליו״ משמע כקטן הנסמך על הגדול